# Report to consider filters from different child objects

Tags: reporting, custom, joined-reports

I have a report which need to consider filters from different child objects. Like i have object A as parent, Object C,D as childs. I need to create a report on object A where it need to consider fields from Object C and D in filters.Please share any ideas.

Comment: did the solution work for you? If so could you please mark my answer as the best answer?

Answer (score 2):

You could use a Cross Filter.

1. Start building the report as usual when you get to the screen where you can drag and drop fields onto the report look at the pane towards the top of the screen. There is an "Add" button next to Filters. Click on the dropdown arrow next to "Add".
   [image]

2.You will notice in the filter pane that a new line will appear with 3 fields. The first field holds the value of the primary object in the report. The second field determines whether it is looking for primary object records "with" or "without" child object records. The last field determines the child object whose fields you need to filter by. So if I was looking for all accounts with Account Feed records. I would select Account for the first field, "With" for the second field, and Account Feed as the third field value.
[image]

3. In the example above there is a "Add Account Feed Filter" option in blue letters. This is used to filter by the child object which in this case is Account Feed. Click on this option and a new line will appear in the pane with three fields. The first is to select the child object field you need to filter by. the second is to choose an operator (examples: =, contains, <,>) and the last is to specify the value that the operator is looking for. 
   [image]

4.Add another cross filter as needed and run the report. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Are you using any standard report type for this report, i don't see any filter to check with,without in child object in my reports. And Here we are considering only one child object. is it possible to include filter on other child object too(because in report type we can select one child object)

Comment: @RaviTeja I'm using the standard Account report and adding a cross filter. Are you clicking on the Arrow next to Add or are you clicking directly on the dropdown button? You want to click directly on the dropdown or the cross filter option will not appear. You can use more than 1 cross filter if needed. Also, what edition of Salesforce are you using?